# Reconcile FullSimplify vs Reduce on Simple Problem

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

Can `FullSimplify` be coerced to give an answer here? If not, is it easy to say why?

```
FullSimplify[(1 + 1/(k + 1))^(k + 1) > (1 + 1/k)^k, 
 k > 0 && k \[Element] Integers]
```

Note that `Reduce` gives the correct answer with the same information.

```
Reduce[(1 + 1/(k + 1))^(k + 1) > (1 + 1/k)^k && k > 0, k, Integers]
(* k \[Element] Integers && k >= 1 *)
```

Comment: Documentation for `TransformationFunctions` shows an example in which `FullSimplify` uses `Reduce`.

Comment: `FullSimplify` is not designed to be a solver.